# Why does the layer list context menu not open anymore?

Tags: qgis, layers, ubuntu

I cannot access layers properties (i.e. change color, filter by query, anything).
The mouse right click doesn't do anything.

Is there a way restoring qgis to default?

Ubuntu 12.04, QGIS 1.8

Comment: could you access the layer properties before or did it not work for you from the start?

Comment: if you need to restore QGIS settings under Linux just delete the ~/.qgis and ~/-config/QuantumGis folders

Comment: _Kurt_ - I could access it. it suddenly disappeared.
_Giovanni_ - Thanks, moving these two files away solved the problem out (though loosing many of customization...)

Comment: Opss... I forgot to mention to backup that folders? :)

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a symptom of something I encountered today where the layers panel was deactivated and the order panel activated after I restarted QGIS. In the order panel, everything looks like the layers panel but of course there are no context menus on legend items.

Comment: This was the fix for myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to restore QGIS settings under Linux just delete the ~/.qgis and ~/-config/QuantumGis folders (backup them first if you have any particular setting you may not want to loose).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I solved it as Tim mentioned:

I closed the layers panel and just enabled it again (in the view tab). Afterwards, it was working fine again. I think this started, when I was moving the layers panel, due to the use of an external monitor.

Best,

Ziga

Answer (score 0):

In the view menu, scroll down to panels and select layers (not layer order), then you will see the symbol under the layer name. In this case you can right click and go to properties.